# role of init plays when creating an array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Say I wanna create an array of images and i used this:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

what role does init really play here? won't it work if I simply use:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray alloc];
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: While I don't know the answer of this question, I don't know why you'd even *want* to know this. Even if the init is pointless, at some point, it might not be. You shouldn't care what happens in classes you don't control when you don't need to. Just use them like you're supposed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you absolutely cannot just say `[NSMutableArray alloc]`. Calling a method on the results of sending `+alloc` to *any* class is absolutely incorrect unless that method is one of the `-init...` methods. All `+alloc` does is reserve the memory for the object. It's basically equivalent to calling `calloc(sizeof(class), 1)`. The `-init` method is crucial to actually initialize the object into a working state.

Comment: To add to this great answer... this is even more evident when you actually see what you get - `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSMutableArray alloc] class]);` returns the an instance of a private framework class  `__NSPlaceholderArray`. This is why you almost always call `alloc/init` as nested calls.

Answer (score 1):

This applies not just to arrays, but to any Objective-C class that can be instantiated: `alloc` allocates memory to hold the instance but doesn't put anything in it, and `init` actually initializes an object in that memory location.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For the best performance when using NSMutableArrays, you always want to use `initWithCapacity:25` or thereabouts. This clears enough memory for a reasonable amount of rows, or entries. If you leave it at init, I believe it will init to initial capacity 0, which means you will have to allocate new memory every time you add something to it, which will hurt your apps' performance.

Comment: Where did you come up with that advice? Providing a specific capacity is rarely useful unless a) you know precisely how many elements you have ahead of time, or b) you're going to put a *lot* of stuff in the array and you want to tell it that ahead of time. Giving it a capacity of `25` is almost certainly pointless.

Comment: my apologies. I was taught giving it a non-zero capacity that is in the ballpark of what the final number should be was always preferred.

Comment: That may be true if you have a very large array, although even then you'd probably want to overestimate (or it will still have to grow). But I'm talking thousands of elements, if not more.

Comment: interesting. Could you point me towards where you learned this so I can read more?

Answer (score 0):

Though there are lots of "swizzles" inside Objective-C to short-circuit the scheme in some cases, in the theoretical model `alloc` creates (allocates from heap) space for the object only.  The contents of the space is essentially random -- whatever was left over from the previous object to occupy that location.

After `alloc`, `init` initializes the space in a class-specific fashion.  For an NSMutableArray, this means that a header is created (the first part of which is actually created by the `super` call to `init` for NSObject) and things like the number of array entries in use are initialized.

Note that for NSMutableArray you can invoke the `array` "convenience" method rather than `alloc/init`, to perform the equivalent of `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`.  And for any class you can invoke the `new` "convenience" method to perform the equivalent of `[[SomeClass alloc] init]`.